# Which is best practice of getting state from redux to component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Example 1:**

**Component1:**

```
<Fragment>
   <span> Hello world</span>
   <component2 {...this.props} />
</Fragment>

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(component1)
```

## (or)

**Example 2**

**Component1:**

```
<Fragment>
   <span> Hello world</span>
   <component2  />
</Fragment>
```

**Component2:**

```
    <Fragment>
       <span> Hello world</span>
    </Fragment>

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(component2)
```

In my scenario i want to use state for the component 1 and component 2..So i need to connect to redux in both component1 and 2, So what would you suggest?And which one is best approach

Thanks

Comment: So, is Componet 1 some kind of container for Component 2? Your two examples and scenario is not the same here. You are saying you want to use the state in both components but in your examples you are using the state only in one component.

Comment: It really depends, but I don't think passing a lot of `...this.props` typically yields the best separation of concerns and or produces modular components.  I find this conceptually helpful: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Comment: Nice one @JoshuaR. This is why I'm trying to understand OP's intention here. But probably since both components use the state, it is better to use a container and pass the related data to those presentational components.

Answer (score 1):

If the Second component is a child of the First component you should mapStateToProps in the First component and then pass it via props to the second component. Just like you did on the first example!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends. In general you try to `connect` "high" in the component hierarchy and pass down props in order to keep as many dumb components as possible. But beware, if you connect really high, then every time the store changes, a lot of component will be rendered for nothing (unless they are pure). Don't optimize before you have a problem, but keep that in mind.

My rule of thumb is one connected component per "topic" in the store. If a component `connects` to get two things and passes one thing to a child and the other thing to another child, then I'd consider moving the connect down to each component. But no hard rules here, only guidance.

Comment: Thanks sylvain..and one more thing that i need to get clarified...So if i need to do two api calls for my state..Which approach do u suggest?  two actions in componentdidmount.. or  one action and making two api calls inside it..

Comment: If the two calls are to satisfy a single intent then I think the action should hide that details from the component and do both calls. Otherwise one action per call.